# Algortihm for clustering 2d grid-like scattered points

Tags: machine-learning, regression, clustering, computer-vision, dbscan

I struggle to find a way to cluster points scattered on a 2D map. The points are mostly following parallel lines (more or less curvy) and are crossed by other parallel lines in another direction.
Here is a generated example with mock data, with a color per cluster :
[image: generated clustered points]

Assuming the perpendicular lines would not be there, DBSCAN would be the advised algorithm for clustering the points along the parallel curvy lines, but with a perpendicular line all points are merged into a unique cluster (as seen below). Hough transform is not working as soon as the lines are not completely straight.

[image: dbscan is not working well as there are crossing points clusters]

Would it be worth considering to train a neural network with randomly generated data ? I am not sure how to build one in this case as the number of output clusters is not known and always the same. Plus I would have thought that  be a more "mathematical" algorithm for this kind of problem.